# Speed of nested if vs for loop

Tags: c, performance, embedded, interrupt, pic

I recently came across this piece of code in an interrupt service routine (ISR):

```c
#define MAX_CHANNELS 4
static uint16_t volatile* ADCVALS[MAX_CHANNELS] = {
    &ADC1BUF0, &ADC1BUF1, &ADC1BUF2, &ADC1BUF3
};
static uint8_t CHANNELS = 0;
static uint16_t volatile* volatile BUFFER_IDX[MAX_CHANNELS];

void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _AD1Interrupt(void) {
    *(BUFFER_IDX[0]++) = *ADCVALS[0];
    if (CHANNELS >= 1) {
        *(BUFFER_IDX[1]++) = *ADCVALS[1];
        if (CHANNELS >= 2) {
            *(BUFFER_IDX[2]++) = *ADCVALS[2];
             if (CHANNELS >= 3) {
                *(BUFFER_IDX[3]++) = *ADCVALS[3];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It copies between 1-4 register values into memory, depending on the value of `CHANNELS`, which is a value between 0-3 which is set elsewhere in the program via a setter function.

I found the nested if's extremely ugly and changed it to this:

```c
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= CHANNELS; i++) {
    *(BUFFER_IDX[i]++) = *ADCVALS[i];
}
```

which promptly broke the ISR. This is an embedded system, PIC24 architecture, 64 MHz clock. The ISR is severely time constrained and must finish within 1 µs. The for loop is apparently too slow, while the nested if is fast enough.

My question, then, is two-fold:

1. Is there a less ugly way to do what the nested if clauses do, without slowing down the ISR?
2. Why is the for loop so much slower? I would have expected the compiler (xc16) to be smart enough to generate similar asm for both (at `-O2`).

Comment: For arrays, a loop condition like `i <= CHANNELS` is almost always wrong. Usually something like `i < CHANNELS` is correct.

Comment: Also, have you looked at the generated assembly code? What *is* `CHANNELS`? Is it a macro (common convention is to use all-uppercase words for macros, not for variables) or an enumeration?

Comment: `CHANNELS` is a value between 0-3, where 0 means copy one value, and 3 means copy four. `BUFFER_IDX` is an array of pointers to a preallocated memory region. The region is split into 1-4 sections, depending on the value of `CHANNELS`. So `i <= CHANNELS` is correct, since the loop should run for `CHANNELS == 3`  but not for `CHANNELS == 4`.

Comment: The final if condition should probably be `if (CHANNELS == 3)` instead of `if (CHANNELS >= 3)`, since the only valid values for `CHANNELS` is 0-3. In that case, I believe the two code examples are equivalent, no?

Comment: As already mentioned, you should look and compare the generated assembly. It is hard to predict performance by looking at the C code alone. If you have issues in high performance code, you cannot just blindly trust compiler to do the right thing.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense and cannot be answered without knowing the type/declarations of `BUFFER_IDX` and `CHANNELS` and so on. Start with disassembling the original code and take it from there. The only thing I can tell you from this code is that you shouldn't be using naive types such as `int` when coding embedded systems. In case of PIC, using `int` may make the code needlessly slow for nothing gained and the compiler might not be able to optimize away such basic mistakes.

Comment: @abessman As for why `int` is slow, it's pretty obvious. It's an 8-bit MCU so swap it for `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= CHANNELS; i++) {
    *(BUFFER_IDX[i]++) = *ADCVALS[i];
}
```

Is

```
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cdqe
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-80+rax*8]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cdqe
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-48+rax*8]
        lea     rsi, [rax+4]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        movsx   rcx, ecx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-48+rcx*8], rsi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
.L2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        jle     .L3
```

And

```
*(BUFFER_IDX[0]++) = *ADCVALS[0];
if (CHANNELS >= 1) {
    *(BUFFER_IDX[1]++) = *ADCVALS[1];
    if (CHANNELS >= 2) {
        *(BUFFER_IDX[2]++) = *ADCVALS[2];
        if (CHANNELS >= 3) {
            *(BUFFER_IDX[3]++) = *ADCVALS[3];
        }
    }
}
```

Is

```
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-80]
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-48]
lea     rcx, [rax+4]
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-48], rcx
mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
jle     .L2
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-72]
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-40]
lea     rcx, [rax+4]
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rcx
mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
jle     .L2
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-64]
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
lea     rcx, [rax+4]
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rcx
mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2
jle     .L2
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-56]
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
lea     rcx, [rax+4]
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rcx
mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
```

How you can see nested if will do less jumps but current compilers can optimize it and with -O3 flag you will get something like this

```
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        test    eax, eax
        js      .L2
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+48]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        test    eax, eax
        jle     .L2
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+56]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+24]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        sub     eax, 1
        jle     .L2
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+64]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        cmp     eax, 2
        jle     .L2
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+72]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+40]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
.L2:
```

That has +- same performance as nested if-s

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I suspected `-O3` might make the for loop faster, but I'm using the free version of xc16 which only goes to `-O2`. I suppose I'm stuck the the nested if's for now.

Comment: @abessman on -O2 it is loop and it really little bit slower, but code more readable

Comment: Performance of some x86 and a PIC are vastly different things. It's completely senseless to optimize in favour of branch prediction for example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna go out on a limb ('cuz I don't usually get this close to the metal).

```
switch( CHANNELS ) {
    case 3: *(BUFFER_IDX[3]++) = *ADCVALS[3]; /* Fallthroughs all the way down */
    case 2: *(BUFFER_IDX[2]++) = *ADCVALS[2];
    case 1: *(BUFFER_IDX[1]++) = *ADCVALS[1];
    default:*(BUFFER_IDX[0]++) = *ADCVALS[0];
}
```

This is 'prettier', and *trades-off* branching with the fetch/assign operations.
Would be nice if someone familiar with Assembly and performance code would please (kindly and gently) evaluate this alternative.

---

**EDIT**
New information about the relationship of ISR duration and # of 'channels' read suggests this might be an alternative that is *easier on the eyes*.

```
void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _AD1Interrupt(void) {
    *(BUFFER_IDX[0]++) = *ADCVALS[0]; if (CHANNELS == 0) goto doneHere;
    *(BUFFER_IDX[1]++) = *ADCVALS[1]; if (CHANNELS == 1) goto doneHere;
    *(BUFFER_IDX[2]++) = *ADCVALS[2]; if (CHANNELS == 2) goto doneHere;
    *(BUFFER_IDX[3]++) = *ADCVALS[3];
doneHere:
    ; // a "sequence point"
}
```

One has to overcome one's aversion to `goto`. The compiler is indifferent. Coders should be too.

Comment: Be careful on GCC warnings too.

Comment: @tilz0R Yes, this is "rough"... I only use an old compiler, not as 'finicky' as current versions.... Just wondering about the C -> assembly of this. Probably worse than a modern, clever optimiser would achieve... Noted, though. Thank you...

Comment: There's no obvious reason why this would be faster or slower than a for loop. Older embedded systems compilers are known to optimize switch statements poorly, however. The PIC compiles in particular always had a real nasty reputation in regards to pretty much everything, including optimizations. Only one way to tell and that's to disassemble with the compiler used.

Comment: I actually tried this already. It is faster, but not as fast as the nested if's (and not fast enough, unfortunately).

Comment: @abessman I think this is not place with bad performance

Comment: This is not the same as the OP's code when `CHANNELS` is greater than 3.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Moot point now that th OP has commented here that this is "not fast enough", but... 3rd comment under the original question, OP writes "CHANNELS is a value between 0-3,.." Just going on the clues at the time... All good... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I did as several commenters suggested and looked at the assembly generated by the compiler for the different codes. I also realized that the 1 µs time constraint is only valid for the case where `CHANNELS == 0`. For values greater than zero, the program bottlenecks elsewhere, which relaxes the time constraint on the ISR somewhat.

Here's the asm for the nested if's:

```
mov _BUFFER_IDX,w0
mov _ADC1BUF0,w1
mov w1,[w0++]
mov w0,_BUFFER_IDX
mov.b   _CHANNELS,WREG
bra z,.L79
mov _BUFFER_IDX+2,w1
mov _ADC1BUF1,w2
mov w2,[w1++]
mov w1,_BUFFER_IDX+2
sub.b   w0,#1,[w15]
bra leu,.L79
mov _BUFFER_IDX+4,w1
mov _ADC1BUF2,w4
mov w4,[w1++]
mov w1,_BUFFER_IDX+4
sub.b   w0,#2,[w15]
bra z,.L79
mov _BUFFER_IDX+6,w0
mov _ADC1BUF3,w5
mov w5,[w0++]
mov w0,_BUFFER_IDX+6
.L79
retfie
```

And here it is for the for loop:

```
mov #_CHANNELS,w6
mov.b   [w6],w6
ze  w6,w6
mov #_ADCVALS-2,w3
clr w0
mov #_BUFFER_IDX,w5
.L79:
add w0,w0,w2
add w5,w2,w2
mov [w2],w1
mov [++w3],w4
mov [w4],[w1++]
mov w1,[w2]
inc w0,w0
sub w0,w6,[w15]
bra leu,.L79
retfie
```

These are all single-cycle operations, except for `retfie` (return from interrupt), which takes 6 cycles. For the case `CHANNELS == 0`, the nested if's use a total of 12 cycles, while the for loop uses 21.

For the switch-case suggested in another answer:

```c
switch( CHANNELS ) {
    case 3: *(BUFFER_IDX[3]++) = *ADCVALS[3]; /* Fallthroughs all the way down */
    case 2: *(BUFFER_IDX[2]++) = *ADCVALS[2];
    case 1: *(BUFFER_IDX[1]++) = *ADCVALS[1];
    default:*(BUFFER_IDX[0]++) = *ADCVALS[0];
}
```

the asm looks like this:

```
mov.b   _CHANNELS,WREG
sub.b   w0,#2,[w15]
bra z,.L81
sub.b   w0,#3,[w15]
bra z,.L82
sub.b   w0,#1,[w15]
bra z,.L80
.L79:
mov _BUFFER_IDX,w0
mov _ADC1BUF0,w5
mov w5,[w0++]
mov w0,_BUFFER_IDX
.L82:
mov _BUFFER_IDX+6,w0
mov _ADC1BUF3,w1
mov w1,[w0++]
mov w0,_BUFFER_IDX+6
.L81:
mov _BUFFER_IDX+4,w0
mov _ADC1BUF2,w2
mov w2,[w0++]
mov w0,_BUFFER_IDX+4
.L80:
mov _BUFFER_IDX+2,w0
mov _ADC1BUF1,w4
mov w4,[w0++]
mov w0,_BUFFER_IDX+2
bra .L79
retfie
```

which uses 18 cycles for `CHANNELS == 0`.

For curiosity, I also tested a do-while loop:

```c
uint16_t i = 0;
do {
    *(BUFFER_IDX[i]++) = *ADCVALS[i];
} while (i++ < CHANNELS);
```

which turns out to be the slowest of the bunch at 22 cycles:

```
mov #_ADCVALS-2,w3
mov #_CHANNELS,w6
mov.b   [w6],w6
ze  w6,w6
inc w6,w6
clr w0
mov #_BUFFER_IDX,w5
.L79:
add w0,w0,w2
add w5,w2,w2
mov [w2],w1
mov [++w3],w4
mov [w4],[w1++]
mov w1,[w2]
inc w0,w0
sub w0,w6,[w15]
bra nz,.L79
retfie
```

I am a bit surprised that a difference of only 9 cycles is enough to break the time constraint, but I suppose the ISR must have been only just fast enough, so those extra cycles pushed it over the edge.